# Add CLLocationManagerDelegate to a separate class

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

I would like to remove the **CLLocationManagerDelegate** from my ViewController and add to a separate class and make it reusable. I'm quite new to swift so I'm asking your help maybe you can point me in the right direction.

My goal is to call my LocationHandler class every time when I want the user's location and most of the times I would like to handle the location differently (e.g. just save it as it is or other time check the location and if it meets certain rules then save it etc...)

I would like to pass in a function to my LocationHandler class if it possible to handle the location change.

> something like this: (this is just a pseudo code, I don't know how to do it properly in swift)
>
> let locationHandler = LocationHandler()
>
> locationHandler.handleLocationChange = (locations: [CLLocation]) - > {...}
>
> locationHandler.getCurrentLocation()

My first problem is when I create an instance from my LocationHandler the getCurrentLocation function is running properly but the didUpdateLocations never rise (I think there is something with the delegation)

Second is I have no idea how to pass a function into a class as a parameter

here is my LocationHandler class

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationHandler: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func getCurrentLocation(){
     
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
                case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                    print("No access")
                case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                    print("Access")
                @unknown default:
                break
            }
            } else {
                print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
        
        
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
          if let location = locations.first {
              print("Found user's location: \(location)")
              //do something with the location
          }
      }
      
      func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
          print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    
    
    
}
```

and I use it in the viewcontroller like this:

```
  let locationHandler = LocationHandler()
  locationHandler.getCurrentLocation()
```

Comment: Is your `LocationHandler` instance a property of your view controller? You obviously want to make sure it’s not falling out of scope and being deallocated. I’m also not seeing where you’re starting the location services. You probably don’t want to just request the location, but rather turn on location services so that it has a chance to warm up and get increasingly more accurate locations.

Comment: @Rob, yes, the problem was that I created the instance in the function level, when I moved to vc level then it start working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you have to ensure that the `LocationHandler` instance is a property of the view controller, not a local variable. You want to make sure it doesn’t fall out of scope and is deallocated before the delegate method has a chance to be called.

Comment: Also what do you mean by turn on the location service, in my example I want the user's location once are you suggesting even if I want it once I should run the service constantly?

Comment: If you call [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation) on a physical device, you’ll see a series of location updates start coming in which are more and more accurate (i.e. with [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy) that are smaller and smaller). Often the first `CLLocation` you get won’t be that accurate. Make sure to test on physical device, not the simulator, to get a sense of the pattern in practice.

Comment: How can I just take one from that series at the time when the user presses the "this is where I'm" button?

Comment: Look at the built-in Maps app on your physical iPhone as a practical example. Often when you first start it (assuming you weren’t doing something else to get an accurate location), it will show you on a map with a large radius to reflect the `horizontalAccuracy` values, and it will generally slowly get more and more accurate. If you want accurate locations in your app, you need to give the GPS a chance to “warm up” and come up with increasingly accurate location information.

Comment: If you’re just trying to figure out someone’s general location (e.g. “nearest cell tower” level of accuracy), the first values are good enough. Another technique is to start location services well before the user has a chance to hit the “where am I button”, so by the time they get there, you’ve got a fighting chance of having an accurate location. Or, like the Uber/Lyft apps, show the user a `MKMapView` with `showsUserLocation` so the user can see it slowly lock into their location and let them adjust the location manually if they so choose. There are a number of ways to tackle this...

Comment: Okay I have an idea, the app is start storing the location updates (e.g. last ten) and when the user presses the button I just take the latest one, that must be more accurate then a freshly started one.

Also like this idea "slowly lock into their location and let them adjust the location manually if they so choose. "

Comment: Most of the time, just keeping track of the most recent location (with a non-negative `horizontalAccuracy`) is sufficient. Or if you’ve got location services started, you can retrieve the information listed under [getting location attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation#topics) directly from the `CLLocationManager` (as it’s keeping track of the latest and greatest, too, assuming you have location services on, of course). But if you retrieve location info without having started location services, you might not get accurate info at first...

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't know that. Thank you Rob!